# Is Up after some verbs optional?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, difference, adverbs, phrasal-verbs

From time to time, I see the preposition *up* appearing alongside a verb or a verb phrase and doesn't add anything to the meaning (or at least, it seems so).

Examples:

> Buckle (*up*)! We have a long journey ahead of us!
>
> People Snuggle (*up*) to each other.
>
> Let's finish this (*up*)

In those sentences, is the particle optional? Because, (to me, at least) they have the same meaning as the verb/verb phrase itself.

Comment: Just a related note: those two-word verbs might come handy when rhyming  matters :-)

Answer (score 2):

The "up" does change the meaning and the "feeling" of the expression.

"Up" tends to indicate "completeness"

"Buckle" (without an "up") sounds like a command from an Army Sergeant. It doesn't fit the situation of a driver giving a friendly reminder to a passenger.

"Snuggle up" sounds warm and friendly. You could snuggle up with your children in front of the TV.  You don't say "snuggle *to* each other". And "snuggle each other" sounds like something approaching sexuality.

"Let's finish" and "Let's finish up" are similar in meaning, but there is a formality to the first and a warmth to the second.

So "up" is not optional.  It is almost required in the first,  gives a different meaning in the second, and adds friendliness in the third.